# Gráfico que atualiza a cada n segundos

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-charts

Estou usando Google Charts e preciso fazer um gráfico que atualize tanto os valores do eixo x quanto quanto do eixo y a cada n segundos.

Preciso que sejam usados 50 dados a cada atualização, por isso usei um 
`SELECT max(id) FROM tabela_arduino` para ler o último valor inserido no database. 
Tentei chamar esse valor no for para plotar o gráfico, mas o gráfico não é gerado. Alguém poderia ajudar a resolver isso?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
die("Não foi possível conectar: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("banco_arduino");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM tabela_arduino");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   printf("ID: %s", $row["max(id)"]); 
}

echo  mysql_free_result($result);

$i=0;
$sql = "select * from tabela_arduino";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);

?>


function desenharGrafico(){

    var dados=new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dados.addColumn('number', 'Registro');
    dados.addColumn('number', 'Talalla');

    dados.addRows(<?php echo $i ?>);

    <?php 
    $k = $i;

    //mudanças a partir  daqui
         $p = $row['max(id)'];

    for ($i = ($p-50); $i<$p; $i++){
    ?>
        dados.setValue(<?php echo $i ?>, 0, '<?php echo $id[$i] ?>');
        dados.setValue(<?php echo $i ?>, 1, <?php echo $sensor1[$i] ?>);

    <?php
    }
    ?>

    var options ={
        title: 'Gráfico ECG',
        width: 1280, height: 480,
        colors:['red'],
    legend: {position: 'bottom'}
    };

    var grafico = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    grafico.draw(dados, options);
};
```

Comment: Você poderia implementar um setInterval(), em JS, que faça a chamada do código php por ajax. Isso funcionou pra mim quando quis fazer um chat simples.

Comment: Estou quase conseguindo, mas estou com um problema para colocar o último valor gerado dentro do for. Acho q minha variável $p e o $row não tem o mesmo formato, talvez por isso o gráfico não é plotado. Tem alguma forma de converter esse $row ?       
 $p = $row['max(id)'];